# Deny access to URI in HAproxy

Tags: haproxy

I want to deny access for few URI for eg:- /info/some. below is the config i am using but still getting 200 when doing curl.

acl bl_info path,url_dec -m beg -i /info/some

acl bl_para path,url_dec -m beg -i /param/some

http-request deny if bl_para

http-request deny if bl_info

Please suggest what is wrong here and what i should do ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this

```
acl restricted_paths path -m beg -i /info/some /param/some
http-request deny if restricted_paths
```

Comment: dcorbett:- Thanks for help, I was using two diff. ACL instead of one, now its working . Could you please help in understanding if there is any reason why two ACL's didnt work.

Comment: Please help in this query, if i have configured a domain in HAproxy and NATEd it to public, is it that all other uri's will be blocked or not.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you ask again and be more specific? Feel free to join us on Slack to chat in detail. `slack.haproxy.org`

Comment: Joined slack channel. Thanks for invitation. Have put the question in haproxy-slack. Please give your input. Thanks